# PHPUnit Selenium - how to check text on a button

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, automated-tests

I am trying to assert this button in my PHP script :

```html
<button data-action="show-more" class="btn btn-link btn-invisible more padded">Button test...</button>
```

I need to verify that the "Button test..." text is there. I have tried text, partial text,like this :

```
$this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::linkText('Button test...'));
$this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::partialLinkText('Button test...'));
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Striezel of course, I have added it to the question